# How to parse "people everywhere"?

Tags: adverbs, parsing, noun-phrases

What's the correct way to parse the following sentence?

> People everywhere are celebrating the landing of the Apollo 11 mission.

On the one hand, *everywhere* typically acts as an adverb and is clearly an adverb in the following, similar sentence:

> People are celebrating everywhere the landing of the Apollo 11 mission.

On the other hand, it seems like *people everywhere* is acting like a noun phrase, and it's *people everywhere* who are doing the celebrating.

Which way is correct, or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many kinds of adverb, there is some latitude in where an adverb appears in a sentence. Generally, for adverbs of place, the adverb goes either after the verb, or at the end of the clause that it modifies. In this case, the verb is celebrating, and the clause is "people are celebrating", so both standard options produce the same sentence:

> People are celebrating **everywhere** the landing of the Apollo 11 mission.

This sentence just doesn't sound right: but the problem is even bigger when we try to use similar adverbs of place:

> People don't like **here** dogs
>   People don't like dogs **here**

The first one is definitely wrong, and the second just doesn't convey the same meaning as

> People **here** don't like dogs

I think that we can explain this by saying that, although the dictionary says it's an adverb, we are thinking of its meaning as the prepositional phrase **in this place**, which can modify either a verb or a noun. What we want to say is

> People **in this place** don't like dogs

Words like **here**, **there** and **everywhere** can be used to modify nouns and verbs. Their role as adverbs (modifying a verb) is undisputed, but their ability to modify nouns is not easy to explain. They are not adjectives, because they are placed **after** the noun that they modify, not before. Their role cannot therefore be defined by conventional grammatical terms, and is equivalent to that of a prepositional phrase.